# iPhone test flight xcode7 xcode8

Tags: iphone, testflight

I have built a application in Xcode 7 with Push Notification using test- flight in development.  I also have a created a script to push notification to the devices using the token  of the devices that I stored in a database.

I simple flag the devices in the database and my scripts read the tables and send a notification to the device(s). Works!

All was well until xcode8.

Now The only way the scripts work is if I "attach" the devices to the mac and build and install the app using the attached cable. I then detached the devices and the scripts works.

If I "archive" the app to iTunes and then using test flight as an external user, i then install the app from test flight, I never get a notification when I run the scripts.

So basically, If I attached the device locally and build, install using a cable it works great. but if uploaded to iTunes and using test flight it does not.

below is as much screen shots

/Users/webcastman/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-10-26 at 1.55.39 PM.png

/Users/webcastman/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-10-26 at 2.14.20 PM.png

/Users/webcastman/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-10-26 at 2.15.12 PM.png

/Users/webcastman/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-10-26 at 2.16.13 PM.png

Answer (score 0):

The first step in sending a remote notification is to establish a connection with the appropriate APNs server [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html):

•Development server: api.development.push.apple.com:443

•Production server: api.push.apple.com:443

When you are installing app in your device through Xcode, I think its build using development provision profile if you have selected Automatic in codesign settings. and when you are archiving and uploading on testflight its build using Distribution profile.

You need to customize your script to send notification for development and distribution(Production) app.

When you are installing app in your device through Xcode, I think its build using development provision profile.

if you are using gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2195, change it with production url.

•Sandbox: gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2195. (for development)

•Production: gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195. (for production)

you also need different APNS certificate (.p12 or .pem- whatever you are using in your script) for Development and production build.

After changing this, you will start getting notification for builds installed through test flight too.